# don't let adverts appear near each other jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ads

[**Here is my DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/222/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var insertionTemplate = jQuery(".hiddenAdBox").eq(0).html(),
        insertionTarget = jQuery('ul'),
        insertionTargetChildren = insertionTarget.find('li'),
        insertionFrequency = 2;

    var random;
    for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
        insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
    } 

});
```

I have list of items, also need to show ads randomly when you refresh page. Now when ads count is 2 (`insertionFrequency = 2`) there is a time when they appear near each other but it shouldn't be so. How can I detect it and don't let ads appear near each other?

Attaching screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _appear near each other_? Side by side, vertically and horizontally?

Comment: attached screenshots @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: `insertionFrequency` sounds and looks like how many ads to show. But the position seems to be picked completely at random? Is that the intended idea? Then what you want is to make sure that no two random numbers are next to eachother, nor at `x` interval from eachother.

Comment: is there any way to prevent appearing ads side by side horizontally at least? @Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent ads **horizontally** you can do it as below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
    if(insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).next('.placeforad').length || insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).prev('.placeforad').length) 
    //check whether its previous li or next li has ad with class .placeforad
    {
        i--; //decrease the count so as to come up with separate random number
    }
    else
       insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/NXzcx/223/)**

But for **vertical** prevention since you do not have equal amount of squares in each row like **1st and 2nd rows have 3 blocks and last row has only 2**, its very tricky to identify horizontal. If there equal amount of squares then some approach might be taken to achieve that too..

---

**Update**

Since you agreed to get 3 blocks in a row the below code will avoid getting ads **horizontally** as well as **vertically**

A small **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/NXzcx/228/)**

```
for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
        var currentElement=insertionTargetChildren.eq(random);
        var addedElement=$('li.placeforad:visible');
        if(currentElement.next('.placeforad').length || currentElement.prev('.placeforad').length)
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i!=0)
            {
                if(addedElement.index() > currentElement.index() &&
                (addedElement.index() - currentElement.index())==3)
                {
                   i--;
                }
                else if(currentElement.index() - (addedElement.index()-1)==3)  
                {
                   i--;
                }
                else
                {
                   insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
                }
            }
            else
                insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aidaghazaryan Check if this is what you were thinking to achieve in horizontal way??

Comment: As I said.. It can be done if even number of boxes are present in each row.. For your scenario I am not sure how we can achieve it.. still will give a try.. Is it possible to change the structure?

Comment: you mean we can prevent for vertical if I have for example 9 boxes, so equal numbers in each row? @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: and if yes how we can do it please? @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: Ok, will wait @Guruprasad Rao